# Audit Log on machine shows login every time channel connected in JSch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am using JSch to fetch data from remote server on brocade switch. A new session is created and a new channel is opened with type as 'shell'. I have few commands which fetches data from this server. I created new Channel for every command and disconnects channel after fetching data.

Now in Audit log on server shows new login for every channel which i created for each command.

Should login be shown for every session created instead of every channel connected?

```
public Session getSession(String hostName,
                                  String username,
                                  String password,
                                  Integer port) throws Exception {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        if (port == null) {
            port = 22;
        }
        session = jsch.getSession(username, hostName, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig("max_input_buffer_size", Integer.toString(100 * 1024 * 1024));
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig("UserKnownHostsFile", "/dev/null");
     session.connect(15 * 1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (session != null) {
            session.disconnect();
        }
        throw new Exception("Error in connecting to: " + hostName, e);
    }
    return session;
}

private Channel getChannel(Session session,String type) throws Exception {
    if (session == null || !session.isConnected()) {
       session = getSession();
    }
    Channel channel = null;
    try {
        channel = session.openChannel(type);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    channel.setInputStream(null);
    return channel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SSH channel does not create a new login.

But it creates a new shell session. Maybe your "audit log" logs shell session as if it were a new login. With a normal SSH client, you typically create only one shell session for each login. So it's easy to mismatch these two things.